# Size of local variable in assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, word-size

I have following C function:

```
void function(int a) {
  char buffer[1];
}
```

It produces following assembly code(gcc with 0 optimization, 64 bit machine):

```
function:
  pushq %rbp
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  movl  %edi, -20(%rbp)
  nop
  popq  %rbp
  ret
```

Questions:

- Why buffer occupies 20 bytes?
- If I declare `char buffer` instead of `char buffer[1]` the offset is 4 bytes, but I expected to see 8, since machine is 64 bit and I thought it will use qword(64 bit).

Thanks in advance and sorry if question is duplicated, I was not able to find the answer.

Comment: This is essentially a question about gcc internals. Wouldn't it also depend on the compiler version?

Comment: `movl  %edi, -20(%rbp)` is spilling the function arg from a register into the red-zone below the stack pointer.  It's 4 bytes long, leaving 16 bytes of space above it below RSP.  You can't infer that `buffer[]` is using up all 16 bytes above that in the red zone, just that gcc did a bad job of packing locals efficiently (because you compiled with `-O0` so it didn't even try).  And it's *definitely* not 20.

Comment: What puzzles me is why the compiler emits a `nop`.

Comment: @melpemone: yes, indeed. The stack layout will also depend on the platform, I guess: Linux, Mac, Windows, just to name a few.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`movl  %edi, -20(%rbp)` is spilling the function arg from a register into the red-zone below the stack pointer.  It's 4 bytes long, leaving 16 bytes of space above it below RSP.

gcc's `-O0` (naive anti-optimized) code-gen for you function doesn't actually touch the memory it reserved for `buffer[]`, so you don't know where it is.

You can't infer that `buffer[]` is using up all 16 bytes above `a` in the red zone, just that gcc did a bad job of packing locals efficiently (because you compiled with `-O0` so it didn't even try).  But it's *definitely* not 20 because there isn't that much space left.  Unless it put `buffer[]` *below* `a`, somewhere else in the rest of the 128-byte red-zone.  (Hint: it didn't.)

---

If we add an initializer for the array, we can see where it actually stores the byte.

```
void function(int a) {
  volatile char buffer[1] = {'x'};
}
```

**compiled by gcc8.2 `-xc -O0 -fverbose-asm -Wall`** [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5ADdUedAGoAZiJbICeVCwh4WBRUwCUijgHY%2BABgCCixXOaaGmRcgRNiigEYjlyzMQcAKw8tMEAIqYAzJHmPGBSAB4J5uEcUVbWqRw2OVk2cgoqahpaLFy6%2BoYmcXl2DkxOLm4e3r7%2BgSFhQbExphYJyVLZGXX2qI54zop6Bj5%2BXMGhEdGxA0kpZmmjNvUTjVMuDNrAbX5RS929a/Ebw1vpmalSRozSQVKkLNKWn6jSAGF%2BPxFMIxBJTFworRPgQfi9XgBrEDQgB0ZgAnAA2IKWKEADgALGYomYsfi3lJCZ8ALZ0SyWL7w0j/KSfQQgRlwqS/V5wWAwKCCiBINA0gAOhzIFAgYslzmIIGA%2BK4pGUUwIAQ5EC8zK8eg8AE9pDDSGKaZh9AB5FgMY08z5YGmsYDOZn4YiYUoyTAch2kTCJL0iTUmz6zTAMMOMPBeYhGgEYSRSU0EYh4Okpl6MF0oYG8GNeDmQV6ocWabR%2BgC0iWQiirVss9eUPuIXlQgkwVaYghp9YA6kwGAx687xAh0uEWJh3M4aezROJJLRXlGpB8mf7WYl8Viq1jCYpgMg6/jUVxFBBcIQSJDoaRFImJVK7yvH/meLD4UZXghMEwsEVCAkRAXFKWpUg6TA74t2kdlOVIbleVIflEBQVBnwVchKDlKUQDwE9aAxeh1QYTViG1XV/X1FgjWjc1LQIG07XdTBnTYN1/Q9L1NB9P1fgDINkBDZNTQjNdTQYWN42IQ1EywaM0wzMNV1zTheH4Qti2AllyzKasrSiAchxHKsxzcSdp1nNiF3BZdV3eT4YIE7dd33Q8CLrIjUUsVFaEva8iE8bh70fDD5QCO8uBMIENN4L8HR/Ug/wAgJKBAsC1wg5y/jgoQEKQhFKS4WlQMZHKWTywq%2BWFYVRXCqVsNlBqFRQZg2DMBk1Q1LVKCogSaLorMzQwi1rVte0BKdF1OKmvBPW9X1mUDYNQ2G8ToykuMEyTRT00zGFVLYPM4oELbtNLPTK2kGs6wbJsq0HYdRw8CyYisoc2LsKs/B7AgzMaBBbKXOgHPXJzmVcvcD1cdrTjMHyfIC/AgtfB8nwi4KoSiGKPwS3lf3/QD0tIZFMukCCoPKyG8o5LlvxQur0MwgImtw1rkAYAB9acAHcuYPbqyN6nU9QNWT6NGxjmMmx02Jm5M5oW3ilv9FbhLWsT9EjZktpkuTduGpSDuzOGTr4AtzvgS6KxYAzEnrABxGRgYkUHKQ3CrtxhmlBBkOsZG82hDwgfsAEkADlsBMK8UdvEL6DClmsaiQlcdO/GipS4mdLJxksoh2C2Xy%2BnErBkrILKzcXKq78QPJc9LFTjEyVoIIuCxKFVTXKJC5r4vqvLvvcoHuvSFbQQyhAQkgA):

```
function:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp               # function prologue, creating a traditional stack frame

    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp) # a, a

    movb    $120, -1(%rbp)  #, buffer

    nop                             # totally useless, IDK what this is for
    popq    %rbp                    # tear down the stack frame
    ret
```

**So `buffer[]` is in fact one byte long, *right* below the saved RBP value.**

The x86-64 System V ABI requires 16-byte alignment for automatic storage arrays that are at least 16 bytes long, but that's not the case here so that rule doesn't apply.

I don't know why gcc leaves extra padding before the spilled register arg; gcc often has that kind of missed optimization.  It's not giving `a` any special alignment.

If you add extra local arrays, they will fill up that 16 bytes above the spilled arg, still spilling it to `-20(%rbp)`.  (See `function2` in the Godbolt link)

I also included `clang -O0`, and `icc -O3` and MSVC optimized output, in the Godbolt link.  Fun fact: ICC chooses to optimize away `volatile char buffer[1] = {'x'};` without actually storing to memory, but MSVC allocates it in the shadow space.  (Windows x64 uses a different calling convention, and has 32B shadow space above the return address instead of a 128B red zone below the stack pointer.)

clang/LLVM `-O0` chooses to spill `a` right below RSP, and put the array 1 byte below that.

---

#### With *just* `char buffer` instead of `char buffer[1]`

We get `movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)  # a, a` from `gcc -O0`.  It apparently optimizes away the unused and uninitialized local variable entirely, and spills `a` right below the saved RBP.  (I didn't run it under GDB or look at the debug info to see if `&buffer` would give us.)

So again, you're mixing up `a` with `buffer`.

**If we initialize it with `char buffer = 'x'`, we're back to the old stack layout, with `buffer` at `-1(%rbp)`.**

Or even if we just make it `volatile char buffer;` without an initializer, then space for it exists on the stack and `a` is spilled to `-20(%rbp)` even with no store done to `buffer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed answer!

Answer (score -2):

4 bytes aligned char ,8 bytes pushed rbp, 8 bytes `a` = 20. Start addres of the `a` is current stack pointer minus 20

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: Calling function pushes a - 8 bytes. Pushed rbp 8 bytes. Aligned to 4 bytes char variable 4bytes.

Comment: The `pushq` instruction was used for rbp; you don't need to also subtract. The space for `a` is made by the caller.

Comment: We're subtracting 20 from `%rbp`, which is all for local variables. `%rbp` is the stack pointer after the return address and the old `%rbp` were pushed. Also, why do you want to align char variables to 4 bytes?